# Can I use my own DLLs with my Xamarin iOS and Android projects?

Tags: dll, clojure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

Can I use my own DLLs with a Xamarin iOS or Android project?

The reason I'm asking is because I want to compile dlls from Clojure CLR, and use them with my Xamarin mobile projects.

Answer (score 6):

Currently the answer for this is 'No' - you cannot use your own existing assemblies but must instead recompile those projects as Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android (MonoTouch or MonoDroid) libraries.

This is because the Xamarin twins are based on old Silverlight profile code and not on full .Net.

This situation is changing currently - Xamarin is rebasing on Mono3/.Net4.5 and Xamarin is working towards PCL support.

However, even with these recent changes I think it is still advisable to rebuild your assemblies for the specific platforms at this time.

Comment: Currently the answer for this is still 'No'?

Comment: except for PCLs the answer remains the same